# Getting a handler error in my IaC stack for an auto-bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3

          s3 = boto3.client('s3')

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            # Get bucket name from the S3 event
            print(event)

            bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']

            # Create a bucket policy
            bucket_policy =json.dumps({
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                      "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        AES256
                        "aws:kms"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:*",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                      "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                      }
                  }
                } ] })


            # Set the new policy
            s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy),
      Handler: lambda_handler.py
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::myrole'
      Runtime: python3.7
  EventRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - CreateBucket
```

I checked the lambda console to see if my function were written in it, and i get the error message as follows:
"Lambda can't find the file lambda_handler.py. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method."
I have the handler as lambda_handler.py, so why isnt this working at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file created would be named `index.py`.

Your `Handler` attribute would therefore be `index.lambda_handler`. This is because the handler defines the filename combined with the function that is called by the Lambda service.

As stated above the file is `index.py` but as Lambda knows your runtime it just needs the `index` part of the filename, then the function defined in your code is `lambda_handler`.

Update the handler value and this should work.

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)